# How to escape the slash in regex when adding map-local option for mitmproxy?

Tags: mitmproxy

I want to add map-local option to map local file `RPC01-3103/1011001/mobile_configs_<UUID>.json` to path *mobile_configs/<*UUID>* for mitmproxy.
However, when I try to escape the slash as below (89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1 is the UUID e.g.), an error is raised by mitmproxy.

```sh
--map-local "/~d text\.com/mobile_configs\/89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1/RPC01-3103/1011001/mobile_configs_89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1.json"
```

The error returned is as below.

```
Cannot parse map_local option /~d test\.com/mobile_configs\/89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1/RPC01-3103/1011001/mobile_configs_89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1.json: Invalid regular expression 'mobile_configs\\' (bad escape (end of pattern) at position 14)
```

To workaround, option need to be set as below.

```sh
--map-local "/~d text\.com/mobile_configs\.89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1/RPC01-3103/1011001/mobile_configs_89bb3783-5a6f-46be-bb9e-291db5c746e1.json"
```

I wonder what is the correct way to escape the slash.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot escape the separator, but you can pick an arbitrary separator. Instead of

```
/example.com/static/~/static   # wrong
```

you can write

```
|example.com/static|~/static
```

for example. Or `@example.com/static@~/static`, or `#example.com/static#~/static`, or ....

Comment: The examples all seem to use the bar character as well https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-features/#map-local